# C++ manipulating numbers in ASCII to stay only in range of letters

Tags: c++, ascii

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Int main() {
cout<<"Give me a letter" <<endl;
char letter;
cin>>letter;
cout<<letter;
(Int)letter;
letter+=2;
cout<<(char)letter;
(Int)letter;
letter-=25;
cout<<(char)letter;

return 0;
}
```

How would I manipulate the numbers in a way so that the numbers will always output a letter. 
ie: if the letter z was chosen and adding 2 is a symbol how would I manipulate it in a way so that it will always stay between the numbers for capital numbers and uncapitalized numbers. Thanks. Please try to keep answers at a beginner level please I am new to this.

Comment: Hint: Character literals like 'a' and 'A' are shortcuts that actually evaluate to the ASCII code for the symbol. So `char c1 = ' ', c2 = 32, c3 = 0x20;` all produce characters with the same ascii code.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(letter > 'z') {
    //do stuff
}

if(letter < 'a' && letter > 'Z') {
    //do stuff
}

if(letter < 'A') {
    //do stuff
}
```

It just depends on how you want to handle the character when it goes into one of the three ranges on the `ASCII` chart in which the characters are not letters.

As a side note, you don't have to cast a `char` to an `int` to do math with it.

```
char myChar = 'a' + 2;
cout << myChar;
```

This will print: `c`

`c` has an `ASCII` value of 2 more than `a`.

Comment: And if `letter` is `é`?

Answer (score 1):

The surest method is to use a table for each category, and do
your arithmetic on its index, modulo the size of the table. 
Thus, for just lower case letters, you might do something like:

```
char
transcode( char original )
{
    char results = original;
    static std::string const lower( "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" );
    auto pos = std::find( lower.begin(), lower.end(), results );
    if ( pos != lower.end() ) {
        int index = pos - lower.begin();
        index = (index + 2) % lower.size();
        results = lower[ index ];
    }
    return results;
}
```

This solution is general, and will work regardless of the sets
of letters you want to deal with.  For digits (and for upper and
lower case, if you aren't too worried about portability), you
can take advantage of the fact that the code points are
contiguous, and do something like:

```
char
transcode( char original )
{
    char results = original;
    if ( results >= '0' && results <= '9' ) {
        char tmp = results - '0'
        tmp = (tmp + 2) % 10;
        results = tmp + '0';
    }
    return results;
}
```

An alternative implementation would be to use something like:

```
results = results + 2;
if ( results > '9' ) {
    results -= 10;
}
```

in the `if` above.  These two solutions are mathematically
equivalent.

This is only guaranteed to work for digits, but will generally
work for upper or lower case *if* you limit yourself to the
original ASCII character set.  (Be aware that most systems today
support extended character sets.)

Answer (score 0):

You can test directly against ASCII chars by using `'x'` notation.  Further, you can test things together using && ("and" respectively"):

```
if ('a' <= letter && letter <= 'z') {
    // Letter is between 'a' and 'z'
} else if ('A' <= letter && letter <= 'Z')) {
    // Letter is between 'A' and 'Z'
} else {
    // Error!  Letter is not between 'a' and 'z' or 'A' and 'Z'
}
```

Or you can use the standard library function `std::isalpha` which handles this for you:

```
if (std::isalpha(letter)) {
    // Letter is between 'a' and 'z' or 'A' and 'Z'
} else {
    // Error!  Letter is not between 'a' and 'z' or 'A' and 'Z'
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with [`std::isalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha)?

Comment: @IInspectable Absolutely nothing, I just think beginners should learn to crawl before walking.  I will add it as an addendum in any case, thanks!

Comment: @IInspectable The original poster spoke of doing things like adding a value to the number, suggesting that he was expecting a contiguous set.  This isn't guaranteed for `std::isalpha`, and unless you are in `"C"` locale (not normally the case where I've worked), the results won't be a contiguous set.

Comment: @IInspectable Also, of course, if `letter` has type `char`, it's undefined behavior to call the one argument version of `std::isalpha` with it.

Comment: @James I don't see the undefined behavior. Surely the integral type promotion from `char` to `int` is well defined. What am I missing?

Comment: @IInspectable The promotion is well defined... an results in values which violate the precondition of `isalpha`.

Comment: @James I'm lost. Which precondition is violated? The only scenario I can think of is that if the underlying type of `char` is `signed char` and ASCII characters are not represented as values from 0 to 127 for a particular implementation.

Comment: @IInspectable The precondition is that the `int` have a value in the range `[0...UCHAR_MAX]` or be `EOF`.  Converting a `char` to `int` will often result in values outside of that range.  (And while ASCII can only be in the range 0...127, I don't know of any system today which uses ASCII.  And even if one did, you'd still have to deal with characters outside the range.)